# Any idea on how to change textarea selection color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I've tried this, but it won't work (in Chrome and IE) in case of textarea :(

```
::-moz-selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}
::selection {
  background: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

Are there ary way to make it possible?
CSS or jQuery any how?

Comment: Other that what you've already tried, there is no way to amend the browser selection colour.

Comment: hmm I think the same but lets see if anyone have idea..

Answer (score 4):

This is only supported in Firefox (and Safari?).

You can do a workaround. Instead of `textarea` use `div` with contenteditable.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/VF4tb/1/

Comment: Changed my answer, hope this helps ;)

Comment: It works on text but not in the input/textarea on Chrome...
Yeah contenteditable'll do the trick !

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to change the background colour of the `textarea` or just the colour of the text inside it? If the latter, then this is what you want:

```
::-moz-selection {
  color: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}
::selection {
  color: #b3d4fc;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/u6CNN/

You can also specify a `background-color` too, by the way.

Comment: I think you're trying thins on Firefox. So please check on Chrome or IE

Comment: `::-moz-selection` is not needed any more, these days. `::selection` works fine in all currently relevant browsers: <https://caniuse.com/css-selection>

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following solution:

```
.YourForm textarea:focus {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If I understand correctly you want to change the background color of a textarea, right?

something like this:

```
textarea{
    /* Change the color of the typed text in the textarea */
    color: #CCC;

    /* Change the background color of the actual textarea */
    background-color: #000;
}
```

or with a class:

css->

```
.classname{
    /* Change the color of the typed text in the textarea */
    color: #CCC;

    /* Change the background color of the actual textarea */
    background-color: #000;
}
```

html->

```
<textarea class="classname">
</textarea>
```